# enabling a macro for all sheet at once to size the same chart that is on more than one sheet so that each chart is updated

Tags: excel, vba

I am curious how to modify my code in VB to allow this macro to run on multiple sheets in the workbook at once. What I would like to do is have this macro size a chart that is used on three sheet in the workbook. It is the same chart (chart 1) and the sizing is controlled by an active x command button. 
this is for excel 2010 .

Any help is appreciated.

```
 Sub thritysecs()
'
' thritysecs Macro
' sets chart to 30 seconds
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=""
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 30
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleWidth 0.699915576, msoFalse, _
    msoScaleFromTopLeft
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="", userinterfaceonly:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is 60 seconds modification for one who know VBA. So, I'll do it for you :)

```
Sub thritysecs()

Dim SH as Worksheet
For each SH in Worksheets
    SH.Activate
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=""
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate

        ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 30
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleWidth 0.699915576, msoFalse, _
                msoScaleFromTopLeft
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="", userinterfaceonly:=True
Next SH
End Sub
```

BTW, for my own purposes I would do it differently but it's not worth for three sheets you have in your workbook.